# Optimization with two constraints using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, lagrange-multipliers

As a part of an problem where i deploy the EM-algorithm i got stuck with the m-step that can be summarized into the below problem:

Consider the following function: $$f(\alpha_{k,l}, \theta_{n, m}) = \sum_{k}\sum_l\left[\sum_n\sum_m r_{k,n,m,l}\right]\ln(\alpha_{k,l}) + \sum_{n}\sum_m\left[\sum_k\sum_l r_{k,n,m,l}\right]\ln(\theta_{n,m})$$

Where as $$r_{k,n,m,l}$$ are our expectations that are already computed(can be though of as constant matrices), the solution should obviously be some expression of these expectations.
$\alpha_{k}$ and $\theta_n$ are probabilities thus the following should hold:

$\sum_n \alpha_{k,n} = 1$ and $\sum_l \theta_{n,m} = 1$

Thus we have two constraints to adhere to:

\begin{align}1 - \sum_l \alpha_{k, l} &= 0\\ 1- \sum_r \theta_{n, m} &= 0\end{align}

and we aim to solve this with Lagrange multipliers.

We construct two functions aiming to capture the constraints:

$g(\alpha_{k, l}, \theta_{n,m}) = 1 - \sum_l \alpha_{k, l}$

$h(\alpha_{k, l}, \theta_{n,m}) = 1 - \sum_m \theta_{n, m}$

Lets start calculating our gradients:

$\nabla_f = <\sum_k\sum_l[\sum_n\sum_m r_{k,n,m,l}]\frac{1}{\alpha_{k,l}}, \sum_n\sum_m[\sum_k\sum_l r_{k,n,m,l}]\frac{1}{\theta_{n,m}}>$

$\nabla_g = <1, 0>$

$\nabla_h = <0, 1>$

thus we are left with the following system of equations:

$\sum_k\sum_l[\sum_n\sum_m r_{k,n,m,l}]\frac{1}{\alpha_{k,l}} = \lambda_{\alpha}$

$\sum_n\sum_m[\sum_k\sum_l r_{k,n,m,l}]\frac{1}{\theta_{n,m}} =\lambda_{\theta}$

$1 - \sum_l \alpha_{k, l} = 0$

$1 - \sum_n \theta_{n, m} = 0$

and from here i am stuck..

i have been told that the solution for $\alpha_{k, l}$ should be: $\frac{\sum_n\sum_m r_{k,n,m,l}}{\sum_l\sum_n\sum_m r_{k,n,m,l}}$ but i cant come up with this answer neither with the lagrange nor without the constraints.

Does anyone see how they came up with this solution?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Can you include more detail in your question (e.g. what types of variables $\alpha,\theta,r$ are, how you came across the objective function, what you have attempted)?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire i added alot of more details now and showed my attempt

Comment: The gradients for $g$ and $h$ are wrong. You should have contributions of $\alpha$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @steward, do you assume $\alpha$ and $\theta$ as the decision variables?

Comment: @A.Omidi yes they are

Comment: @cvanaret fixed

Comment: Btw mosek.com can solve that problem if you want something to compare with.

Comment: @steward, thanks for clarifying. I think you need to take a look again at your constraints. Your first constraint should be $ \sum_n \alpha_{k,n} = 1, \forall k$, but in the second the sum is over $l$ while $\theta$ has indexed over $n,m$. Please, check it again.

Comment: I assume the second constraint outer-loop is over $n$. Now, you have to define two positive lagrangian multipliers, as the sign of both constraints is $=$ those might be negative too, named $\lambda_k$ and $\omega_n$ respectively. By adding these multipliers to the objective function with an appropriate penalty, you would form a Lagrangian dualized function and you can solve it in an efficient manner.